# How to make image fit its container - do it dynamically

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-size

Need help from Html+CSS expert:
I have an angular material design mat-grid-list which should contain in each of its mat-grid-tile 3 elements - mat-radio-button on the left side, and on the right side text in the header and below - an image.
The main problem is that the images represented in Base64 encoding and their dimensions (width and height) are different from one to another.
I would like to have each image located fully in its container, while keeping the right proportions between its width and height.
I can do some manipulation on the image css properties by using the image load event.
The question is what should be the mechanism to do so, or is there another idea\solution ?
here's an emphasis of my idea after seeing one answer:
I would like to fit the full image to the container while making it smaller, when needed - I thought of checking what might be the major constraint - the width or the height -then changing (width\height) it to fit the container, and change the other dimension (height\width respectively) with the same ratio. **I don't mind having unused space in the container - I'm aware that this is one of the side-effects**.

See my code: (the ProfileImage is a base64 encoding)

Html:

```
<div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <mat-grid-list [cols]="numberOfColumns" rowHeight="2:1">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor= "let item of items"> 
        <mat-radio-button value="item.ID">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 90%;">
            <div style="height: 10%;">{{item.Name}}</div>
            <div style="height: 90%;" >
              <img [src]="item.ProfileImage" class="thumbnail" (load)="itemProfileHasLoaded($event, item.ID)">
            </div>
        </div>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

component:

```
  itemProfileHasLoaded(event : any, itemID : number)
  {
    if (event && event.target)
    {
      //I can set here some logic to set their dimensions, but what should it be ? 
      event.target.width = 
      event.target.height = 
    }*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here's the catch :

"I would like to have each image located fully in its container, while keeping the right proportions between its width and height."

If you ever tried to fit a square block in a round hole, you know what's going to happen.

You can NOT fit different ratios into the same container without distortion. So either make the image fit the container and lose ratio, or put it in the background and lose parts of the image.

My advice: use a background image with background-size:cover;

Comment: I think we have a miss-communication problem - I would like to fit the full image to the container while making it smaller, when needed - I thought of checking what might be the major constraint - the width or the height -then changing (width\height) it to fit the container, and change the other dimension (height\width respectively) with the same ratio. I think this is feasible